# Ventana modal en Bootstrap se cierra sola automáticamente al abrirla

Tags: php, javascript, html, bootstrap

Tengo una ventana modal que se abre haciendo clic en un botón pero cuando la abro se cierra al instante, no llega ni a un segundo abierta. Leí en algún foro que agregando el type `button` al botón solucionaba el problema pero no resultó. Probé con `input` y tampoco me funcionó.

El botón es el siguiente:

```
<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginFrm3"><span class="icon fa-print"> 
        </span>Listado</button>
```

El modal es el siguiente:

```
<!-- filtro para impresion de pop up-->

<div class="modal fade" id="loginFrm3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop=”static” data-keyboard=”false” aria-labelledby="loginFrm" aria-hidden="true" position="fixed">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <!-- Form Name -->
        <h4>Impresion de Listado de Participantes</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                                    </button><br>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="register_form" style="padding-left: 20%; padding-right: 20%; padding-top: 5%; padding-bottom: 5%">
          <form class="form-horizontal" name="register" method="post" action="">

            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Seleccione el listado a imprimir:</label>
              <br>
              <a class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block icon fa-save" target="_blank" type="submit" name="submit" style="color: white" href="impresion_listado_participantes_fpdf.php?estado=TODOS"> Imprimir TODOS</a>
              <a class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block icon fa-save" target="_blank" type="submit" name="submit" style="color: white" href="impresion_listado_participantes_fpdf.php?estado=Pagado"> Imprimir Pagos</a>
              <a class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block icon fa-save" target="_blank" type="submit" name="submit" style="color: white" href="impresion_listado_participantes_fpdf.php?estado=No-pago"> Imprimir No Pagados</a>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- filtro para impresion de pop up -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes errado el uso de comillas dobles en el `div` del `modal`, justo en los atributos `data-backdrop=”static” data-keyboard=”false”`. Cambia estas comillas `”` por estas `"`

Puedes probar con el ejemplo que te dejo acá.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
     
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginFrm3"><span class="icon fa-print"> 
    </span>Listado</button>

    
    <!-- filtro para impresion de pop up-->

        <div class="modal fade" id="loginFrm3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" aria-labelledby="loginFrm" aria-hidden="true" position="fixed">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <!-- Form Name -->
                        <h4>Impresion de Listado de Participantes</h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                        </button><br>
                     </div>
                     <div class="modal-body">
                       <div  id="register_form" style="padding-left: 20%; padding-right: 20%; padding-top: 5%; padding-bottom: 5%">
                          <form class="form-horizontal" name="register" method="post" action="">

                             <!-- Text input-->
                             <div class="form-group">
                                 <label>Seleccione el listado a imprimir:</label>
                                 <br>
                                 <a class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block icon fa-save" target="_blank" type="submit" name="submit" style="color: white" href="impresion_listado_participantes_fpdf.php?estado=TODOS"> Imprimir TODOS</a>
                                 <a class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block icon fa-save" target="_blank" type="submit" name="submit" style="color: white" href="impresion_listado_participantes_fpdf.php?estado=Pagado"> Imprimir Pagos</a>
                                 <a class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block icon fa-save" target="_blank" type="submit" name="submit" style="color: white" href="impresion_listado_participantes_fpdf.php?estado=No-pago"> Imprimir No Pagados</a>
                             </div>
                         </form>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
        </div>

  <!-- filtro para impresion de pop up -->

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Es correcto, el error es tipográfico, está usando comillas simples en lugar de comillas rectas. [+Info](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comillas#Inform%C3%A1tica). También es recomendable que revise su código pues tiene varias etiquetas obsoletas.

Comment: @JheymanMejia a qué "etiquetas obsoletas" te referís?

Comment: @azeós hay tres atributos `name` dentro de las etiquetas `a`. En su lugar se recomienda hacer uso de atributos `id`. Tampoco se debe usar el atributo `type="submit"` en elementos diferentes a un botón.

Comment: @JheymanMejia perfecto, estaba buscando *etiquetas obsoletas* y no miré los *atributos*, gracias.